# PHP: get attributes value of xml

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have following xml structure:

```
<stores>
   <store>
      <name></name>
      <address></address>
      <custom-attributes>
          <custom-attribute attribute-id="country">Deutschland</custom-attribute>
          <custom-attribute attribute-id="displayWeb">false</custom-attribute>
      </custom-attributes>
   </store>
</stores>
```

how can i get the value of "displayWeb"?

Comment: there are no criterias, i just want to get the value "false"

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this is use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), you may either loop trough all stores:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $yourXML);

// With use of child elements:
$storeNodes = $dom->documentElement->childNodes;

// Or xpath
$xPath = new DOMXPath( $dom);
$storeNodes = $xPath->query( 'store/store');

// Store nodes now contain DOMElements which are equivalent to this array:
// 0 => <store><name></name>....</store>
// 1 => <store><name>Another store not shown in your XML</name>....</store>
```

Those uses [`DOMDocument` properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) attribute [`childNodes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) or [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Once you have all stores you may iterate trough them with `foreach` loop and get either all elements and store them into associative array with [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php):

```
foreach( $storeNodes as $node){
  // $node should be DOMElement
  // of course you can use xPath instead of getAttributesbyTagName, but this is
  // more effective
  $domAttrs = $node->getAttributesByTagName( 'custom-attribute');
  $attributes = array();
  foreach( $domAttrs as $domAttr){
    $attributes[ $domAttr->getAttribute( 'attribute-id')] = $domAttr->nodeValue;
  }
  // $attributes = array( 'country' => 'Deutschland', 'displayWeb' => 'false');
}
```

Or select attribute directly with `xPath`:

```
// Inside foreach($storeNodes as $node) loop 
$yourAttribute = $xPath->query( "custom-attribute[@attribute-id='displayWeb']", $node)
     ->item(0)->nodeValue; // Warning will cause fatal error when missing desired tag
```

Or when you need just one value from whole document you could use (as Kirill Polishchuk suggested):

```
$yourAttribute = $xPath->query( "stores/store/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id='displayWeb']")
    ->item(0)->nodeValue; // Warning will cause fatal error when missing desired tag
```

*Carefully study manual to understand what type is returned when and what does which attribute contain.*

Answer (score 1):

For example I can parse XML DOM. http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: do you also have an concrete example in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath:

```
stores/store/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id='displayWeb']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [PHP's SimpleXML](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).  That web page has lots of user-supplied examples of use to extract values from the parsed data.